# AttributeError 'tuple' object has no attribute 'get'

Tags: python, django

I have a Django application. But i can't an error that i have been struggling with for some time now.

```
Exception Value: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'get'

Exception Location: /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/middleware/clickjacking.py in process_response, line 30
```

And this is the traceback django provides me.

```
Traceback:
File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in get_response
201.                 response = middleware_method(request, response)
File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/middleware/clickjacking.py" in process_response
30.         if response.get('X-Frame-Options', None) is not None:
```

I have a hard time figuring out why this error occurs. How can i find out where that `tuple` is in my code?

The view:

```
def products(request, category=None, gender=None, retailer_pk=None, brand_pk=None):
    # If the request it doesn't have a referer use the full path of the url instead.
    if not request.META.get("HTTP_REFERER", None):
        referer = request.get_full_path()
    else:
        referer = request.META.get("HTTP_REFERER")

    if gender:
        products = ProductSlave.objects.filter(Q(productmatch__stockitem__stock__gt=0) &
                                               Q(productmatch__slave_product__master_product__gender=gender)).distinct()
    elif brand_pk:
        products = ProductSlave.objects.filter(Q(master_product__brand__pk=brand_pk))
        brand = Brand.objects.get(pk=brand_pk)
    elif retailer_pk:
        retailer = Retailer.objects.get(pk=retailer_pk)
        products = retailer.productmatch_set.all()
    else:
        products = ProductSlave.objects.filter(Q(productmatch__stockitem__stock__gt=0))

    if not retailer_pk:
        filt = create_filtering(productslaves=products, request=request)
    elif retailer_pk:
        filt = create_filtering(productmatches=products, request=request)

    sorting_selected = request.GET.get("sorter", None)

    # q_list is used to store all the Q's
    # Then they are reduced. And then filtered
    if "brand" in request.GET:
        brand_filtering = request.GET.get("brand", None)
        if brand_filtering:
            brand_filtering = brand_filtering.split("|")
        q_list = []
        for filter in brand_filtering:
            if retailer_pk:
                q_list.append(Q(slave_product__master_product__brand__slug=filter))
            else:
                q_list.append(Q(master_product__brand__slug=filter))
        reduced_q = reduce(operator.or_, q_list)
        products = products.filter(reduced_q)

    if "kategori" in request.GET:
        category_filtering = request.GET.get("kategori", None)
        if category_filtering:
            category_filtering = category_filtering.split("|")
        q_list = []
        for filter in category_filtering:
            if retailer_pk:
                q_list.append(Q(slave_product__master_product__product_category__slug=filter))
            else:
                q_list.append(Q(master_product__product_category__slug=filter))
        reduced_q = reduce(operator.or_, q_list)
        products = products.filter(reduced_q)

    if "stoerrelse" in request.GET:
        size_filtering = request.GET.get("stoerrelse", None)
        if size_filtering:
            size_filtering = size_filtering.split("|")
        q_list = []
        for filter in size_filtering:
            if retailer_pk:
                q_list.append(Q(slave_product__productmatch__stockitem__size__pk=filter))
            else:
                q_list.append(Q(productmatch__stockitem__size__pk=filter))
        reduced_q = reduce(operator.or_, q_list)
        products = products.filter(reduced_q)

    if "farve" in request.GET:
        color_filtering = request.GET.get("farve", None)
        if color_filtering:
            color_filtering = color_filtering.split("|")
        q_list = []
        for filter in color_filtering:
            if retailer_pk:
                q_list.append(Q(slave_product__sorting_color__slug=filter))
            else:
                q_list.append(Q(sorting_color__slug=filter))
        reduced_q = reduce(operator.or_, q_list)
        products = products.filter(reduced_q)

    if "pris" in request.GET:
        price_filtering = request.GET.get("pris", None)
        if price_filtering:
            price_filtering = price_filtering.split("|")
        q_list = []
        if retailer_pk:
            q_list.append(Q(price__gte=price_filtering[0]))
            q_list.append(Q(price__lte=price_filtering[1]))
        else:
            q_list.append(Q(productmatch__price__gte=price_filtering[0]))
            q_list.append(Q(productmatch__price__lte=price_filtering[1]))
        reduced_q = reduce(operator.and_, q_list)
        products = products.filter(reduced_q)

    if sorting_selected:
        if sorting_selected == filt["sorting"][0]["name"]:
            filt["sorting"][0]["active"] = True
            if retailer_pk:
                products = products.annotate().order_by("-price")
            else:
                products = products.annotate().order_by("-productmatch__price")
        elif sorting_selected == filt["sorting"][1]["name"]:
            if retailer_pk:
                products = products.annotate().order_by("price")
            else:
                products = products.annotate().order_by("productmatch__price")
            filt["sorting"][1]["active"] = True
        elif sorting_selected == filt["sorting"][2]["name"]:
            filt["sorting"][2]["active"] = True
            if retailer_pk:
                products = products.order_by("pk")
            else:
                products = products.order_by("pk")
        else:
            if retailer_pk:
                products = products.order_by("pk")
            else:
                products = products.order_by("pk")
    else:
        if retailer_pk:
            products = products.order_by("pk")
        else:
            products = products.order_by("pk")

    if brand_pk:
        return render(request, 'page-brand-single.html', {
            'products': products,
            "sorting": filt["sorting"],
            "filtering": filt["filtering"],
            "brand": brand,
        })
    elif retailer_pk:
        return (request, 'page-retailer-single.html', {
            "products": products,
            "sorting": filt["sorting"],
            "filtering": filt["filtering"],
            "retailer": retailer,
        })
    else:
        return render(request, 'page-product-list.html', {
            'products': products,
            "sorting": filt["sorting"],
            "filtering": filt["filtering"]
        })
```

Comment: You can replace these two lines `if "pris" in request.GET:
        price_filtering = request.GET.get("pris", None)` with `price_filtering = request.GET.get('pris', None)`, your first membership check is not required because `get` will never raise an exception.

Answer (score 73, accepted):

You are returning a tuple here:

```
elif retailer_pk:
    return (request, 'page-retailer-single.html', {
        "products": products,
        "sorting": filt["sorting"],
        "filtering": filt["filtering"],
        "retailer": retailer,
    })
```

Did you forget to add `render` there perhaps:

```
elif retailer_pk:
    return render(request, 'page-retailer-single.html', {
        "products": products,
        "sorting": filt["sorting"],
        "filtering": filt["filtering"],
        "retailer": retailer,
    })
```

Answer (score 7):

There is an extra comma "," at the end of `return` function in **views.py**

```
return render(request, 'index.html',{}), #incorrect
```

```
return render(request, 'index.html',{}) #correct
```

Answer (score 7):

Always make sure you have  **render** after 'return', in your views functions

> In my case I had not added the `return render(request, app_name/index.html`
> It took me a lot of time to find this bug and not even one of the answers on stack overflow mentioned it, that's why I posted it here.

[{IMAGE} check the index and register functions and the error indicated below them.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RxM2h.png)

Answer (score 1):

Even taking the commas of the views is as simple of a solution

as-in
this

```
def home(request):
    return render(request, 'index.html')

def hire(request):
    return render(request, 'hire.html')

def handler400(request, exception):
    return render(request, '400.html', locals())

def handler403(request, exception):
    return render(request, '403.html', locals())

def handler404(request, exception):
    return render(request, '404.html', locals())

def handler500(request, exception):
    return render(request, '500.html', locals())
```

Rather than
this

```
def home(request):
    return render(request, 'index.html'),

def hire(request):
    return render(request, 'hire.html'),

def handler400(request, exception):
    return render(request, '400.html', locals()),

def handler403(request, exception):
    return render(request, '403.html', locals()),

def handler404(request, exception):
    return render(request, '404.html', locals()),

def handler500(request, exception):
    return render(request, '500.html', locals())
```

Answer (score 1):

you forgot to add `render` after `return`
so you just need to add  `render`  after  `return`

**The part you wrote(look at the last elif):**

```
elif retailer_pk:
    return (request, 'page-retailer-single.html', {
        "products": products,
        "sorting": filt["sorting"],
        "filtering": filt["filtering"],
        "retailer": retailer,
    })
```

**but it would be :**

```
elif retailer_pk:
    return render(request, 'page-retailer-single.html', {
        "products": products,
        "sorting": filt["sorting"],
        "filtering": filt["filtering"],
        "retailer": retailer,
    })
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Had a similar problem and discovered that the error was from the spacing between the function name and the request

I did this : 
def greet (request, name):
    return render(request, "hello/greet.html", {
        "name": name. Capitalize()
    })

instead of this:
def greet(request, name):
    return render(request, "hello/greet.html", {
        "name": name. Capitalize()
    })

The space between 'greet' and '(request, name)' was responsible for the error
```

Answer (score 0):

simply the problem is, there is no extra comma after the bracket

### before

```
def home(request):
return render(request,'home.html',{}), //error bcz of  extra comma
```

### after

def home(request):

```
return render(request,'home.html',{}) //no  error
```

Comment: Please don't repeat answers

Answer (score 0):

Had the same error, spent some time scratching my head before realizing that in one of my forms, i had:

```
def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs) -> None:
        super(MyForm, self).__init__(args, kwargs)
```

Instead of: *(notice the asterisks before args & kwargs)*

```
def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs) -> None:
        super(MyForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
```

Answer (score -2):

This bug took me so much time to find, and I couldn't find the answer here. Just something similar, so I decided to drop this exact one here:

***Incorrect:***

```
return render(request, 'templates folder directory', {'team': team}, {'form': form})
```

***Correct:***

```
return render(request, 'templates folder directory', {'team': team, 'form': form })
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).