# AttributeError at / 'tuple' object has no attribute 'get' in Django

Tags: python, django

I am having a AttributeError at / 'tuple' object has no attribute 'get', below is the trace path what could be wrong in Django?

```
AttributeError at /

'tuple' object has no attribute 'get'

Request Method:     GET
Request URL:    http://www.example.com/
Django Version:     1.10.5
Exception Type:     AttributeError
Exception Value:    

'tuple' object has no attribute 'get'

Exception Location:     /home/admin/env/lib/python3.5/site-packages     /django/middleware/clickjacking.py in process_response, line 32
```

Python Executable:  /home/admin/env/bin/python
Python Version:     3.5.2

Comment: Possible duplicate of [AttributeError 'tuple' object has no attribute 'get'](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22557014/attributeerror-tuple-object-has-no-attribute-get)

Comment: Please post at least the code for `process_response`.

Answer (score 2):

The clickjacking middleware is calling the response's `get` method. Hence, your view is not returning a [`HttpResponse`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/request-response/#django.http.HttpResponse) instance.

Comment: how do I solve this? My view is just doing "return render(request, my.html')"

Comment: You check your view code and make sure it returns one. Possibly you return `(request, 'template.html')` instead of  `render(request, 'template.html')` or sth similar.

Comment: You could post your view code in the question, which the most relevant part of the issue here.

Answer (score 1):

check the applications views.py file, something is wrong with render or HttpResopose function in return statement. I was getting same error and I was missing render in my return statement.

`def relative(request):
    return render(request, 'basic_app/relative_url_templates.html')`