# internal server error: /robots.txt

Tags: python, django, robots.txt

I am getting an internal 500 server error but the site is not crashing. Below is what comes out on the console and this happens on every route call, both http and api.

```
[23/Jan/2018 16:12:49] "GET /robots.txt HTTP/1.1" 500 58587
[23/Jan/2018 16:12:49] "GET /checkout HTTP/1.1" 200 192777 
Internal Server Error: /robots.txt
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/distpackages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", 
      line 41, in inner response = get_response(request)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/distpackages/django/utils/deprecation.py", 
      line 142, in __call__ response = self.process_response(request, response)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/middleware/clickjacking.py", 
      line 32, in process_response
  if response.get('X-Frame-Options') is not None:
AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'get'
```

Here are the contents of my robots.txt file:

```
User-agent: ia_archiver
Disallow: /

User-agent: Googlebot
Disallow: /

User-agent: Slurp
Disallow: /

User-agent: MSNBot
Disallow: /

User-agent: *
Disallow: /
```

I am not sure which files I should starting looking into to traceback the error as I am a junior dev working alone. Would you guys be kind to guide me in the right direction?

Answer (score 0):

This looks like n issue with your django application and could be a duplicate of [AttributeError 'tuple' object has no attribute 'get'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22557014/attributeerror-tuple-object-has-no-attribute-get)